# IBM Lotus Notes form takes long time to respond to Action Button

Tags: office365, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus, lotus-formula

I have a form which has Action button which does below commands on click:

```
 @SetProfileField("Docket";"CommentDescription";"SignedOff";@UserName);
 @PostedCommand([Compose];"Comment");
 @SetField("SaveOptions";"1");
 @PostedCommand([FileSave]);
 @PostedCommand([FileCloseWindow]);
```

But on clicking on the button, the form gets freeze and it doesn't responds. It gets hanged and have to be killed from task manager by closing Lotus Notes. However this doesn't happen every time. Also this effect is taking place after installing Office365 on the machine. Previously, when Office365 was not installed the issue never took place. But now in order to get around the issue, the user's machine has to be restarted and then perform the same action in the form. Could someone have a permanent solution to this issue? Also is the issue related anyway to Office365?

Comment: What steps have you taken to narrow down the problem? Have you tried removing the first line of the formula? The second line? The last line? Also, have you uninstalled Office365 to see if the problem goes away? Nothing in the code you are showing would seem to have any relationship to Office365, but this code is saving and closing a document and we can't see if there is anything in rest of the code on the form or in the content of the document that deals with Office data, so it's really up to you to figure that out.

Comment: As said, the code works fine sometimes by restarting. So there is no code issues. Also it was working perfectly all the time before installation of Office365.
Apart from Action button issue sometimes users are also facing issues while opening the attachments(word) in a form after installation of Office365, it hangs. This is happening for few users.
So what I really want to know is there any data in Notes directory setup for users that needs to be cleaned.

Comment: Even though there are no code issues, it would be very useful to know which line of code is executing when Notes freezes! That's why I am suggesting that you do some troubleshooting. I doubt that anyone here will be able to give you much advice unless you provide more information, but I personally doubt that cleaning any data from the Notes directory will have any effect on the problem It sounds much more like something either in the form or in the documents is interacting with Office365 and preventing either the save or close window operation from completing.

Comment: My guess is: there is code in QuerySave, PostSave, QueryClose or any related event that produces this error...

Comment: As there is a code @PostedCommand([Compnose];"Comment"); which opens the form and saves it on click of Action button. Now I could see that I cannot open the "Comment" form as well from the view. It freezes. Even I have put Messagebox in the queryopen event and put debugger on, but still on double clicking of the form it freezes and doesn't open.
So that's why when clicking of the Action button it also freezes. What may cause this issue?

Comment: Try to rewrite the code in Lotusscript, then it is easier to debug.